# Validate HTML for missing id in the inputs

Tags: html, validation, gruntjs

I'm trying to do some simple validation of HTML files, to check if all inputs, buttons, textareas and selects, int html document, have their 'id' attribute.

I would like to check it on CI tool and I would like to use Grunt for that check. I couldn't find any relevant information on that topic. I've checked [grunt-html](https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-html) and [grunt-html-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-validation) packages, but seems like it's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest to what you want seems to be [htmllint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmllint) - and its associated grunt task.

It doesn't have a rule for what you want, but you could contribute one - cleaner and more sharable than a custom grunt task :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about tools but you can do a trick like this in jquery

```
$('input, button, select, etc').each(function (index){
  if(this.id)
  {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  }
});
```

Comment: I would like to be able trigger it from the command line. I could probably write some custom grunt task, using your example, but I was looking for something rather "out of the box".

Comment: ok.. don't have much idea about tools and all,Just tried to help you :)